# How to pass quotes from csv to writed file by CsvHelper

Tags: csvhelper

Please, help. Have the question about CsvHelper library. I use dynamic record and wanna pass double quotes as is or may be better change double quotes to single quotes. But library erase quotes all time.

```
var csvHelperConfig = new Configuration();
var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvHelperConfig);
var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>() as IDictionary<string, object>;



LANGUAGE,TITLE,CODE,UPDATED
"EN","English, English, English",1,"01.01.2000"
"DE","German",2,"01.01.2000"
```

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: [ask], and [mre]. Build a short reproduction of your issue. With a short CSV containing bogus data and your test case. You can use Excell to produce the CSV in a few minutes. For now your question is a bit unclear? Do you have unescaped quote? if that's the case we will need this part of the CSV.

Comment: The [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2), should cover those case. Read the section 2. 5/6/7 _"If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote"_, the correct way to espace is using `""`

Comment: Perhaps you are simply looking for `reader.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true;`

Comment: And Btw don't use `dynamic` if you any have informations about what the object really is. `dynamic` is just when you need to tell the program : "I gave up on that type. You will have to figure it out at runtime. And don't ask me question.".

Comment: i mean double quotes on string fields in csv format

Comment: Sorry, Maybe my English is not good enough. I was also talking about double quotes. Your comment does not clarify if the quotes are escaped or not? It does not give information about the validity of the CSV format.

Comment: reader.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true; is passing double quotes as is, but it break CsvHelper library logic. That begin split fields if inside is a comma(csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",").

Comment: That was just a guess. The code you included is the basic declaration of a CsvReader. It give no information on your CSV and not information. Note that the RFC does not address the SingleQuote as 'unclosing' char. Only DQuote should be valid. I'm not interested in your real csv Data, but I have insisted about having a [mre]. A simple 3 row 2 columns bogus csv should be enough to cover basic case.

Comment: i`m sorry. i had been thinking that all string types in csv format mark by double quotes. you are right. thank you.

Comment: @DragandDrop, i just added csv example to the first post. My csv is csv with string types scoped with double quotes.

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue with that sort of input? Here is what I get https://dotnetfiddle.net/JX9btv.

Comment: And here is a version with the nested List `""` converted to a `List<String>` Property : https://dotnetfiddle.net/jCaxa5

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly pretty, but I believe it does what you are asking.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("LANGUAGE,TITLE,CODE,UPDATED");
        writer.WriteLine("\"EN\",\"English, English, English\",1,\"01.01.2000\"");
        writer.WriteLine("\"DE\",\"German\",2,\"01.01.2000\"");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var records = new List<dynamic>();

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var startIndex = 0;
            dynamic dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < csv.Context.HeaderRecord.Length; i++)
            {
                var item = csv.GetField<string>(i);

                var foundIndex = csv.Context.RawRecord.IndexOf(item, startIndex);

                startIndex = foundIndex;

                if (csv.Context.RawRecord[foundIndex - 1] == '"')
                {
                    item = '"' + item + '"';
                }

                IDictionary<string, object> underlyingObject = dynamicObject;

                underlyingObject.Add(csv.Context.HeaderRecord[i], item);
            }

            records.Add(dynamicObject);
        }
    }
}
```